# How to compile with dlib?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, dlib

I face a problem when I use Eclipse to compile with dlib in the platform of Ubuntu.And I have added the library path and the relevant library libdlib.a.

The error message is:
g++ -L/home/my/Documents/dlib-18.18/dlib/test/build/dlib_build -o "FacedetectionProject"  ./src/FacedetectionProject.o   -llibdlib.a
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibdlib.a

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: what if change linker flag to **-ldlib** ?   also you can include dlib/all/source.cpp into your project ant you will not need any libs

Comment: How can I change it to -ldlib ?

Comment: Is it a makefile project or managed build project?